# Powershell string -replace remember first argument value?

Tags: regex, string, powershell, replace

I'm currently working on a powershell script where I have to replace all the expressions with "[A-Z]=" to "(first expression's letter):"

For example "A=" would become "E=", "Z=" -> "Z:" etc..

So in the end I want to remember part of the first argument and paste it to the second argument.

Is there any efficient way to do this ?

```
$quotaTXT3 = $quotaTXT2  -replace '[A-Z]=', '[A-Z]:'
```

Comment: It's absolutely unclear to me what you are after. Edit your question to contain a [mcve] In general I'd suggest to use regular expression with a capture group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for are [capture groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions).

You use them like so:

```
$quotaTXT3 = $quotaTXT2  -replace '([A-Z])=', '$1:'
```